# How to use Flask-Babel to localise data returned by QuerySelectField in a flask_wtf

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, flask-babel

I would like to use Flask-Babel to localise content in the app. Now I understand how Flask-Babel works and it's used to localise static content.

I have created a number of forms using Flask-wtf and they use QuerySelectField to fetch data from the database. Here is the registration form that has a QuerySelectField.

```
from flask_babel import _, lazy_gettext as _l

class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField(_l('Username'), validators=[DataRequired()])
    email = StringField(_l('Email'), validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    country = QuerySelectField(_l('Country'),
                           blank_text=u'-- please choose --',
                           query_factory=lambda: Country.query,
                           allow_blank=False)
    password = PasswordField(_l('Password'), validators=[DataRequired()])
    password2 = PasswordField(
        _l('Repeat Password'), validators=[DataRequired(),
                                           EqualTo('password')])
    submit = SubmitField(_l('Register'))
```

Is there anyway the country values can be localised here using babel instead of having to stored countries in different languages in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the Flask-Babel was used to localize **static content** (strings in `.py`, `.html` etc.), you can't use it for dynamic content that output from the database. For this use case, you may need to use translation services such as [Google Translation API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/) or [Microsoft translator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/translatorapi.aspx).